# VBA copying multiple sections into memory to allocate/paste into a new worksheet

Tags: vba, excel, memory, copy-paste

I'm just wondering if it's possible in Excel/VBA, to specify multiple different sections of data (so you'll have set many Ranges on one worksheet) and save it to memory. So that when you move onto the next sheet, you can access each Section you've saved into memory to the allocated position in the second worksheet. I feel like that would be faster than having to constantly flip back and forth from sheet to sheet, also the code would read a lot cleaner. 
Any thoughts (like if I should even be doing this) or an example code of how I could do this would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Just forego the constant calls to `Activate` and `Select`; they are unnecessary.

Comment: Well for instance, when I set a range (e.g. Set Example=worksheet("Sheet1").Range("A1","B6")) How do I make another variable that would be Copy1=Example.Copy ?

Comment: You're more likely to get helpful suggestions here if you include [some of] your current code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you not just create a union for all data ranges?
for example, if you have a range pointer that jumps around and represents different ranges...

Something like the following....

```
Dim rTotal as range, rPtr as range

Do While Finished = false
    If rTotal is nothing Then
       set rTotal = rPtr
    Else
       set rTotal = Union(rTotal, rPtr)
    End if
Loop
```

rTotal will now have the total union.
By the way, there is also an Area property you can use to segregate the different ranges, but Excel can be 'intelligent' and sometimes merge two adjacent ranges into one. Depends on your circumstance...